# Analytic method for ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

I am studying on a drag force ODE. My question is:

Is there any analytic method to solve $$\frac{dv}{dt}+\alpha v^n=g\\ n \in(1,2]$$ It is somehow look like Bernoulli Differential Equations $y' + p\left( x \right)y = q\left( x \right){y^n}$ but not exactly. It is originated from falling body equation with air drag force.$mg-kv^n=ma$ or $mg-kv^n=m\frac{dv}{dt}$ that divide both sides by $m$ and rewrite as $\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{k}{m}v^n=g$,$g=9.8\ \frac{m}{s^2}$ for the case of $n=1 $ it is easy to solve $v=g\frac mk (1-e^{-\frac kmt})$ but how to do it for the case of $n=\frac 32 \ $ or $n=2 $
Realy I got to struggle with special two cases... can someone help me? I want to solve to at least for $n=2 $ to compare with the solution that I got by numerical solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dv}{dt}+\alpha v^n=g$$
$$\frac{dt}{dv}=\frac{1}{g-\alpha v^n}$$
$$t=\int \frac{dv}{g-\alpha v^n}+constant$$
$$t=\frac{v}{g}\:_2F_1\left(1\:,\:\frac{1}{n}\:;\:1+\frac{1}{n}\:;\:\frac{\alpha}{n}v^n \right)+c$$
$\:_2F_1\:$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html

$v(t)$ is the inverse function, generally not nice.

In some particular values of $n$ the solution is simpler.

Case $n=1 \quad$ linear ODE $\qquad\qquad v(t)=\frac{g}{\alpha}+c\:e^{-\alpha\;t}$

Case $n=2 \quad$ Riccati ODE $\qquad\qquad v(t)=\sqrt{\frac{g}{\alpha}}\tanh\left(\sqrt{\alpha g}\:(t-c) \right)$

Case $n=\frac12 \quad$ the solution involves the LambertW function.